# Talend connection over VPN

Tags: mysql, linux, vpn, etl, talend

I have a [Talend Data Integration](https://www.talend.com/products/data-integration) server (subscribtion product) and I want to load date to/from a MySQL database which is reachable over VPN tunnel.
Both servers are linux servers (RHEL).
Could you please suggest how can I connect from Talend to MySQL over VPN? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create an SSH tunnel which makes MySQL appear on your localhost:3306 address then connect to that.